# trying to get N rows from a specific table against 1 row from another table

Tags: laravel, orm

i have three tables `categories`,`brands`,`products`, each table has column tagkey
and I'm trying to retrieve all categories with 2 brands for each category with 5 products for each brand that has a certain tag in laravel
i wrote this query

```
Category::with(['brands' => function($query) use ($tag) {
    $query->with(['products' => function($productQuery) use ($tag) {
        $productQuery->where('tagkey', $tag->key)->limit(5);
    }])->where('tagkey', $tag->key)->limit(2);
}])->where('tagkey', $tag->key)->get();
```

but this query get me 2 brands total for all categories and 5 products total for all brands.
[this is the expected output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg6AS.png)
I appreciate any insights or advice. Thanks!

Comment: From https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads **The limit and take query builder methods may not be used when constraining eager loads.** . That's because they will be applied to the queries for the related models which attempt to load them all at once.

Comment: @apokryfos is right. eager loading is not currently supported. But that will be possible in Laravel 11: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/49695. You can upgrade later on. In the mean time, we try to think of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

When You try to add limit in eager loading model it will return only limited number in total. Internally eloquent runs 2 queries first one to get your categories (select * from categories) and it takes all the id from categories and then runs new query to fetch brands (select * from brands where category_id in (catgories_ids) limit 15).So in order to solve this problem you can run your own sql queries:

```
select * from 
(select brands.*,@row_number:=case when @category_id=brands.category_id then @row_number+1 else 1 end row_num,@category_id:=brands.category_id CategoryId 
from brands join (select @row_number:=0,@category_id:=0)asdasd 
where brands.category_id in (ids) ) asdas 
where row_num <=2
```